# TableView Cell alignment causing some space on the top

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout

Don't know why but I am having this issue when using with storyboard and autolayout.
Below is the screen shot of simulator...gray is the tableview background to understand the table frame, but my cell is not placed at the top side of table, causing some top space.
I don't want it.[image]

It works well with ios6.

Comment: Is your tableViewStyle `Grouped`?

Comment: it might be one of the auto layout constraints that's creating problem. What are the constraints you have for the button? Does it work if you disable autolayout?

Comment: @Subhransu: tried by deasabling autolayout no hopes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code :

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

If not works than use this :

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-35, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: better if we make check as: `   if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])`

Answer (score 1):

Set the TableView's header like this

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 0.01f)]
```

or set the tableview's header to nil like this

```
self.tableView.header = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

- I don't know exactly what is causing this issue.
- 1. There may be a chance that you have set the height for header in section, but no view for header defined.

     -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return ;
      }
- Other than this I don't think any autolayout explicitly causing your cell to move down.
- Cause your autolayout will either within your cell or table and its superview.

Comment: it works neatly on ios6 with autolayout also.. I am not using headerfor table...last button is footerview

Comment: place a uiview between view controller view and tableview and check.

Comment: - Please try adding more rows to your table and see how its rendered.

Comment: @raja: top space remaining same...while scroll starting after that fixed space